# How do I close a specific database connection in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mocha.js

In my app I have two database connections open. One of the connections is for the standard development database. The second connection is for a seperate database that I specifically use for testing.

Let's say the first connection is open and my app is running, and I decide I want to run my tests. The first test that runs opens the second connection, or closes it if it already exists.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import 'dotenv/config';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

describe('Mocha testing setup', function() {
  it('Connect to testing database and clear old data', function(done) {
    mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_TEST).then(db => {
      done();
    }).catch(err => {
      mongoose.connection.close().then( => {
        console.log('Testing database has been closed.');
      }).catch(done);
    });
  })
})
```

When I run:

```
mongoose.connection.close()
```

How can I be certain that it will not close the first connection. I need to be certain that it will close the connection to the testing database not the development database.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle your connections like this :

So each of your connection will be stored into a single variable which represent it and that you can use to interract.

```
  this.db = mongoose.createConnection(url, opt);

  // What happend when we connect
  this.db.once('open', () => {});

  // What happend on error
  this.db.on('error', (err) => {});

  this.db.on('disconnected', () => {});

  this.db.on('connected', () => {});

  this.db.on('close', () => {});
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help. Not sure but somewhere I saw like handling two separate connection can be done as,

```
const devConn = mongoose.createConnection();
devConn.open("mongodb://localhost/development",callBack1);

const testConn = mongoose.createConnection();
testConn.open("mongodb://localhost/test",callBack1)
```

After that you can close any connection by writing something like,

```
devConn.close(callBack2);
testConn.close(callBack2);
```